# Trying to mix boxlayout and floatlayout in Kivy Python but when I run I get a blank black box

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am extremely new to kivy and Python but I managed to get a few simple buttons with some random generation that outputs to a label running in floatlayout. I wanted to implement aspects of BoxLayout to make it easier to align buttons vertically on the left hand side of the app so I could use the rest of the open space for displaying the output.  What I am seeing when I tried to implement aspects of BoxLayout is no errors but just a big black box when I run the program. What am I missing?

````
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random
from kivy.core.window import Window
#Setting the size of the window that opens
Window.fullscreen = False
Window.size = (300,300)

#Deciding if user can resize the window or not
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
Config.write()

class Generators(FloatLayout,BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Generators,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.defaultlayout=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.dcanvas = FloatLayout()
    #Setting up the labels
        self.name_label = Label(text = "Random Table Output", size_hint=(.2, .15),pos_hint={'x':.5, 'y':.9})
        self.main_label = Label(text = "Press a random generator on the side and output will display here.", size_hint=(1, .55),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.35})

    #Setting the details of every button
        self.louche_button = Button(text = "LOUCHE", size_hint=(.15, .10),pos_hint={'x':.0, 'y':.9},on_press = self.update)
        self.randomname_button = Button(text = "Random Name\n    Generator", size_hint=(.15, .10),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.8},on_press = self.name_gen)
        self.food_button = Button(text = "Food", size_hint=(.15, .10),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.7})
        self.go_button = Button(text = "Go", size_hint=(.15, .10),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.6})
        self.walk_button = Button(text = "Walk", size_hint=(.15, .10),pos_hint={'x':.0, 'y':.5})
        self.inventory_button = Button(text = "Inventory", size_hint=(.15, .10),pos_hint={'x':0, 'y':.4})

#Adds the widgets for each button and label designed above
        self.defaultlayout.add_widget(self.louche_button)
        self.defaultlayout.add_widget(self.randomname_button)
        self.defaultlayout.add_widget(self.food_button)
        self.defaultlayout.add_widget(self.go_button)
        self.dcanvas.add_widget(self.walk_button)
        self.dcanvas.add_widget(self.inventory_button)
        self.defaultlayout.add_widget(self.main_label)
        self.defaultlayout.add_widget(self.name_label)
        
        

    def update(self,event):
        LOUCHE = ['LOCALITY: Something specifically related to the current environment happens.\nThe buildings now on fire. The ground collapses. It\'s flooding. Moonquake!' , 'OFFER: Offer a bargain, an extra, or a perk for a cost.\noffer a better position, with risk. Offer a temptation.', 'UNEXPECTED DANGER: Make something up or roll it up at random.\nTie it in if you want now or worry about how it fits in later', 'CALLBACK: Use something that they\'ve given you. A backstory element.\nAn off-handed comment. Gear. A character sheet aspect', 'HARM: Deal damage', 'END SOMETHING: End an ongoing effect, bonus, or fictional advantage. Take a \nresource away, something you possess, whether it\'s a piece of gear, \nan ability, or an ally']
        self.main_label.text = (str(random.choice(LOUCHE)))
        
    def name_gen(self,event):
        first = ['Bob ', 'Aaron ', 'Keisha ']
        last = ['Quebman', 'Harp', 'DaFuq']
        self.main_label.text = (str(random.choice(first))) + (str(random.choice(last)))

class app1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Generators()
if __name__=="__main__":
    app1().run()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending two classes that have differing implementations of the same method (`do_layout()` for example) is a bad idea. You do not need to extend a class in order to use that class. You can build your `App` display using `FloatLayout` and `BoxLayout` directly.

Here is an example where the `Generators` class extends just `BoxLayout`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random
from kivy.core.window import Window

#Setting the size of the window that opens
Window.fullscreen = False
Window.size = (300,300)

#Deciding if user can resize the window or not
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)

kv = '''
Generators:
    orientation: 'horizontal'   # Generators is a BoxLayout
    BoxLayout:   # left side of App
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 0.25, 1
        Button:
            text: "LOUCHE"
            size_hint: (1, .10)
            pos_hint: {'x':.0, 'y':.9}
            on_press: root.update()
        Button:
            text: "Random Name\\n    Generator"
            size_hint: (1, .10)
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':.8}
            on_press: root.name_gen()
        Button:
            text: "Food"
            size_hint: (1, .10)
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':.7}
        Button:
            text: "Go"
            size_hint: (1, .10)
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':.6}
        Button:
            text: "Walk"
            size_hint: (1, .10)
            pos_hint: {'x':.0, 'y':.5}
        Button:
            text: "Inventory"
            size_hint: (1, .10)
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':.4}
    FloatLayout:   # Right side of App
        size_hint: 0.75, 1
        Label:
            text: "Random Table Output"
            size_hint: (.2, .15)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'top':1}
        Label:
            id: main_label
            text: "Press a random generator on the side and output will display here."
            size_hint: (1, .55)
            pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':.35}
'''

class Generators(BoxLayout):
    def update(self, *args):
        LOUCHE = ['LOCALITY: Something specifically related to the current environment happens.\nThe buildings now on fire. The ground collapses. It\'s flooding. Moonquake!' , 'OFFER: Offer a bargain, an extra, or a perk for a cost.\noffer a better position, with risk. Offer a temptation.', 'UNEXPECTED DANGER: Make something up or roll it up at random.\nTie it in if you want now or worry about how it fits in later', 'CALLBACK: Use something that they\'ve given you. A backstory element.\nAn off-handed comment. Gear. A character sheet aspect', 'HARM: Deal damage', 'END SOMETHING: End an ongoing effect, bonus, or fictional advantage. Take a \nresource away, something you possess, whether it\'s a piece of gear, \nan ability, or an ally']
        self.ids.main_label.text = (str(random.choice(LOUCHE)))

    def name_gen(self, *args):
        first = ['Bob ', 'Aaron ', 'Keisha ']
        last = ['Quebman', 'Harp', 'DaFuq']
        self.ids.main_label.text = (str(random.choice(first))) + (str(random.choice(last)))

class app1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app1().run()
```

Comment: Hey John, I think I understand what you are saying but do you have a code example? I think seeing it visually will clear it up more than just reading your explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks John this is great!